# Invalid time format in exported excel sheet

Tags: php, excel

Iam exporting the user data (like his last logged in time) into an excel sheet, but to my surprise, i found that the time column in the excel sheet is showing as ######.

Iam storing the user login time as datetime in the users table.
But i dont understand why this time is not displayed properly in excel sheet.

Did anyone face a similar problem ?

Comment: expand the column and you see it right, http://www.ehow.com/how_4445648_autofit-column-width-excel.html

Comment: Yes, to my surprise, it is working now after manually expanding the  column in the excel sheet. Anyways, is there a setting that i can do from my code, like setting the column width?

Comment: "is there a setting that i can do from my code, like setting the column width?" - That depends on exactly how you are creating the excel sheet... what library are you using to create the xls file?

Comment: i cant remember it exactly, and i just ran an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

expand the column and you see it right,

ehow.com/how_4445648_autofit-column-width-excel.html